# CMake: Howto test for compiler, before enable a language

Tags: cmake, fortran, nasm

In my project some code can be optional compiled in a different language (nasm & fortran), but it's also fine to compile the project without having these compiler installed. E.g. on Windows.

I would like to check if the the compiler are installed, before enabling the languages with enable_language

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
enable_language(Fortran)
```

If I use `enable_language` without an additional check, CMake stops with an error message.

(At the moment I check for `if (MSVC)` as workaround.)

Btw. I have a similar problem with the check for Qt. The check don't stop with an error, but generate a lot of noisy warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use [check_language](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckLanguage.html#module:CheckLanguage) to check if a language can be enabled.

Comment: Thank, it's working.
It would be nice, if there are some cross references between enable_language and check_language.