# CMake check if CUDA environment exists without find_package

Tags: cmake, cuda

As stated here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html

```
find_package(CUDA)
```

is a deprecated way to use CUDA in CXX project. We have to use

```
project(MY_PROJECT LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
```

but how can I detect whether the current platform supports CUDA. The goal is to exclude some targets from build if CUDA is not installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60320941/681865

Comment: it throws "Could not find compiler set in environment variable CUDACXX:" error. And what I want is let's say a boolean flag to be used furthe in my project

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution thanks to a comment posted on the question referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60321228/681865) Stack Overflow answer, and in turn [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckLanguage.html#module:CheckLanguage) piece of documentation.

Here is a code snippet :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
include(CheckLanguage)

project(my_project)

check_language(CUDA)
if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
        message(STATUS "CUDA is OK")
else()
        message(STATUS "No CUDA")
endif()
```

Comment: Glad it helped. For a point of reference (having never actively used CMake before), all I did was google "cmake test if language is installed" and the linked [SO] answer was the first hit... I have edited the links into you answer -- my comment might not hang around, bu the links to the answers in your answer will and will make everything more prominent for future searches and people with the same question